'cls' is not running. The screen will not be erased
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void ViewHP(int health)
{
    printf("HP = ");

    for (int i = 0; i < health; i++)
    {
        printf(" ♥ ");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        ViewHP(5);
        system("cls");
    }
}

'cls' is not running. I wrote #include <stdio.h>, #include <stdlib.h>, and #include <windows.h>, and the code is normal.
When executed, cls does not work. There seems to be no error in the code, and the execution itself does not work. Even if you use cls, the screen will not be erased, but it will still be printed out. This is not the case even though I search a lot, so I leave a question.

How do you know the screen is not erased if your program is in a loop and redraws it again immediately?

The #include <windows.h> is not needed because the program only calls standard C library functions.

"the execution itself does not work" there's no error check of system(3) call that can give you a clue

Side note: Using system("cls") is not the recommended way to clear the screen. See this Microsoft documentation page for different ways to perform this action.

If you write Sleep(5000); (which pauses the program for 5 seconds) immediately below the line system("cls");, then you will be able to see whether this line is working or not.

Originally, 'HP = ♥♥♥♥♥' should be printed, the screen should be erased, and the screen should appear to flicker over and over again.

When I used Sleep(5000); the screen didn't disappear after 5 seconds and the output came out again, so cls doesn't seem to work.

Like the SO community pointed out in comments, the while() loop never paused so that you could ensure that the clear screen method ( system("cls")) actually worked.  The following code remedies that problem by its logic in main() . . .
. . . and also introduces an alternate, MS windows-based (per your code) clrscr() function.  clrscr() is something of a hybrid of things mentioned here and yet is very primitive -- simply writing enough newlines ( \n ) to the console/terminal to match the console/terminal height.
Because it is primitive, it should work for many years to come -- across both consoles and terminals -- regardless of which dominates over time.  That is because enough newline ( \n ) characters should cause scrolling and screen-clearing (by pushing previous lines up) until some strange new, unpredictable day in the future.
This code is compiled and tested by me just minutes ago:
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> /* _getch() */
#include <windows.h>

int clrscr(void)
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int i, bSuccess = 0;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };    /* home for the cursor */

    if(hStdOut)
    {
        if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi))
        {
            for(i=0; i < csbi.dwSize.Y; i++) /* for() console window height . . . */
                putchar('\n');  /* . . . print newlines to clear the screen. */
            /* Home the cursor just like cls does: */
            if(SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coordScreen)) 
                bSuccess = 1;
        }
    }
    return bSuccess;
}

void ViewHP(int health)
{
    int i;

    printf("HP = ");
    for (i = 0; i < health; i++)
    {
        printf(" ♥ ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
    int done=0;
    while (!done)
    {
        ViewHP(5);
        system("pause"); /* pause to see results of screen fill. */
        clrscr();  /* Can still use system("cls") if you prefer. */
        /* Pause again to ensure clear screen is working correctly: */
        if(_getch() == 27) /* ESC key quits . . . */
            done = 1;
    }
    return (0);
}


@chichi -- hello -- if this answer works out for you please consider selecting it.  Thx
